# How well suited is python 3.7 for NLP and machine learning currently? Is there a better version I should go with?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I am trying to learn and get familiar with using python for NLP and machine learning. I have python 2.7, 3.6, and 3.7 currently on my computer but I dont know which one I should start with. Is 2.7 too limited? Is 3.7 not fully supported with relevant packages yet? I have tried to look around the web but I am having a tough time articulately forming my question for a search engine. Any advice or direction is greatly appreciated!

Comment: There are lots of advantages to both python 2 and python 3. Answers to this question will be largely based on personal preference and opinion rather than expertise on the subject. [Questions like that aren't on-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

It's usually a good idea work on the latest stable version of the language, because a series of improvements are made.

In your case, to work in NLP/ML area, you probably will use some lib like NLTK/Spacy (for NLP) and Numpy/Pandas/Scikit (for ML) and both of them are compatible with this versions (the libs have stable versions and updates too).

So, if you're starting, you can use the latest stable version (3.7.*) of the language and same for the libs.

Answer (score 0):

If you need very specific libraries that will only work with older versions of Python, that is really the only reason to pick 2.x or 3.6 or older over 3.7.

Backwards compatibility is not bad and for any scripts you may already have, or any libraries you have the source code to, conversion from an old version is generally not too much of an issue, if needed at all.

3.7 has gotten better in almost every way, removing more issues than adding them, improving on the language and 3.x has been around for so long now, that nearly all libraries and packages worth using out there are available for it.

NLTK, TextBlob, CoreNLP, spaCy, gensim, they all work on 3.7 as far as I know. Perhaps you had something very specific in mind? I recommend googling around for the libraries and frameworks you want to try and then googling those names specifically with "python 3.7 " and you'll be able to quickly ensure you won't have problems.